# how can I use ruby to extract the email address from a <mail to> tag?

Tags: ruby, mailto

My program takes an input from Slack.  When an email is provided, Slack automatically converts it to a mail to tag:

`<mailto:timxxxx@gmail.com|timxxxx@gmail.com>`

The email addresses are the same.

I want to easily extract the email IF it is provided in this form, but if the email comes through another channel where it hasn't been reformatted, take the email.

Comment: I thought since the mailto tag was a standard there was some way to "reverse" outing in that format.

Comment: My apologies. I did not read the question carefully enough. I deleted my earlier comment and will delete this one when you've seen it. You may wish to delete your comment also, considering it is now an orphan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that if the string looks like:

```
<mailto:....>
```

the dots represent one or more email addresses, and if more than one, they are separated by `"|"`. Further, I assume that part of the string need not be checked to confirm it contains valid email addresses, properly separated. In those assumptions are correct, you don't need a regex to extract the email addresses:

```
def extract_addresses(str)
  return nil unless str.start_with?('<mailto:') and str.end_with?('>')
  str[8..-2].split('|')
end

addresses = extract_addresses "<mailto:timxxxx@gmail.com|timxxxx@gmail.com>"
  #=> ["timxxxx@gmail.com", "timxxxx@gmail.com"] 
puts addresses ? "mailto format" : "not mailto format"
mailto format
puts "addresses are the same" if addresses && addresses.uniq.size == 1
addresses are the same

addresses = extract_addresses "<the quick brown dog jumped over the lazy fox>"
  #=> nil
```

Comment: Cool let me try. It is the same format always. Another way is the real email is betwee mailto and the |

Comment: And the addresses are always the same. What happens is that Slack converts an email entry into this format for each email.

Comment: cool, i went with this solution.  The emails on both sides should always be the same, but i just use .first method on it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what the other format would be, but you could use a regex to identify strings in the given format and verify that both sides of the `|` are indeed the same address. The code would be something like:

```
def get_mail(str)
   matches = /<mailto:([\w\-\.]+@[\w\-\.]+)\|([\w\-\.]+@[\w\-\.]+)>/.match(str)

   if (matches.nil? || matches[0] != matches[1])
       str
   else
       matches[0]
   end
end
```

Note that some special cases of email address might fail the matching, as there are some crazy emails that are valid, but this would work for basic cases. If needed you can modify the regex to use a more inclusive email matching.

Comment: I will try. It only converts to this tag if an email.